# MVC 5 Razor - Label isn't updated from class annotation

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, html-helper, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a simple example.
Two class. User and Company like :

```
public class User() {
    public int UserID { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "User name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Company")]
    public int CompanyID { get; set; }

    public virtual Company Company { get; set; }
}

public class Company() {
    public int CompanyID { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Company")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<User> Users { get; set; }
}
```

My problem is in the Create and the Edit views of the User.
The label for "Name" is displayed correctly in "User name" but the label for "CompanyID" stay displayed at "CompanyID" (the drop down list is created correctly with all Companies). I want the label display "Company" like I make it in the class.

I've try to change my view but all I do block compilation so I'm lost.
I'm begginer in MVC so excuse me if it easy to do but I don't see it.

**Edit (add Create View code) :**

```
@model Intranet3.Models.User
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Add a user";
}
@using (Html.BeginForm(null, null, FormMethod.Post, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-horizontal form-bordered" })) {
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    <div class="row-fluid">
        <div class="span12">
            <div class="box">
                <div class="box-title">
                    <h3>
                        <i class="icon-table"></i>
                        New
                    </h3>
                </div>
                <div class="box-content nopadding">
                    <div class="form-horizontal">
                        @Html.MyValidationSummary()

                        <div class="control-group @Html.ClassErrorFor(model => model.Name)">
                            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Name, new { @class = "control-label" })
                            <div class="controls">
                                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name)
                                @Html.MyValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name)
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="control-group @Html.ClassErrorFor(model => model.CompanyID)">
                            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CompanyID, "CompanyID", new { @class = "control-label" })
                            <div class="controls">
                                @Html.DropDownList("CompanyID", String.Empty)
                                @Html.MyValidationMessageFor(model => model.CompanyID)
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-actions">
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Create</button>
                            <button onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("Index","User")'" type="button" class="btn">Cancel</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

**Edit 2 :**
Problem solved by delete the string force in Labels.
So this :

```
@Html.LabelFor(model => model.CompanyID, "CompanyID", new { @class = "control-label" })
```

Need to be

```
@Html.LabelFor(model => model.CompanyID, new { @class = "control-label" })
```

Comment: please show ur view code

Comment: The attribute usage is just fine. Try `clean` and `re-build`. Let us know if the issue still persists. And show your view code.

Comment: @NitinVarpe Create View added. Cleaned and rebuilded a lot of times...

Comment: If you solved the problem, please post your answer and accept it, or accept one of other people's answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why have u passed parameter CompanyId

```
@Html.LabelFor(model => model.CompanyID, "CompanyID", new { @class = "control-label" })
```

Should be

```
@Html.LabelFor(model => model.CompanyID, new { @class = "control-label" })
```

Comment: That the problem. It was auto-generated by VisualStudio so I don't see it before.

Answer (score 0):

@Html.TextBoxFor(c => c.CompanyID, new { data_bind = "text:Contacts.FirstName", @class = "form-control" })

If you have knockoutjs binding